# How to print properly accents when logging an NSArray?

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

The following code

```
NSString * firstString = @"à" ;
NSString * secondString = @"é" ;

NSArray * myArray = @[firstString, secondString] ;

NSLog(@"%@ and %@", firstString, secondString) ;
NSLog(@"%@", myArray) ;
```

prints out

```
TestAccentsArray[3883:303] à and é
TestAccentsArray[3883:303] (
    "\U00e0",
    "\U00e9"
)
```

**Is there a way to print properly accents when logging an `NSArray`?**

---

PS : I want to log the `NSArray` if possible. I know that with a loop and logging the elements of the `NSArray` it will work.

Comment: try my answer...it should work

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
for (NSString *str in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", str) ;
}
```